# Mysql Insert multiple rows in multiple tables with transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im using `mysql-node` and I have two tables. One is called `owners` which have the columns `id`, `name`. And the other one is called `owners_address` which has `id`, `address_id` and `owner_id` . So, I need to insert multiple owners and insert those in the second table at once with transaction and I have a defined address_id. So, at first, I tried to:

```
  //Begin transaction
  //Insert into owners my array of owners (Example: ['Andrew', 'Jonathan', 'John'])
  //Get last insert id by LAST_INSERT_ID() function
  //Create dynamic query with FOR and increments LAST_INSERT_ID() with the given address_id. (Example: [2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4] etc..).
```

The problem is that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` give to me the last insert id before the first execution, and what I need to build the dynamic query is the last insert id after the first execution. How can I get the LAST_INSERT_ID() after add owners to table owners ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Can you give code or mysql cmd? I can't get you with your description.

Comment: I just figure out What I had to do. Should I delete this post or answer my question?